# Repeating Results PHP Query While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm retrieving  Data from MySQL with Ajax and PHP without refreshing , The issue is my results that are displayed duplicate . I only want one instance of a username to display back .

The table that contains username has a UNIQUE INDEX set not to allow the duplicate names however its my (I think) my while statement as I believe this is causing the results to duplicate

How can I Please ? Correct this to only display once instance of each username . Sorry in advance that I don't already Know but hopeful someone can help .

```
  <?php
  include('..\db.php');
  $con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
  $q1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl1 username");

  $data="";

  // if the search is true 
  if(isset($_POST['search']))
  {
// 
  $var = $_POST['search'];

  if($query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROMtbl1 WHERE username LIKE '%$var%'"))

  {
    // possible creating duplicate results 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $data .= $data . '<div>' . $row['username'] . '</div>'; 

    }
    echo $data;
  }
  }else{
 }
?>


<html>

<head>

        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"
          integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



        <script>

            $(function(){
                $('.input').keyup(function(){
                    var a = $('.input').val();
                    $.post('livesusers.php',{"search":a},function(data){
                        $('#display').html(data);
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>


</head>
<body>

 // form to input text  and search
  <form action= "livesusers.php" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name="search" class='input'>
  </form>
  <div id='display' style='margin-top:100px'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get proper data in `echo $data` ?

Comment: I have tried using DISTINCT in my Query but still it duplicates + The  results from $data DO show proper data Only its duplicates the names so if I have two names that start with K it will show each name twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your while loop as you said. you are concatenating twice on each cicle.

Try to replace this:

```
// possible creating duplicate results 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $data .= $data . '<div>' . $row['username'] . '</div>'; 

    }
    echo $data;
```

to this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $data .= '<div>' . $row['username'] . '</div>'; 

}
echo $data;
```